# Need help to resolve Windows 10 Error Code: 0xc0000098 (your PC/Device needs to repaired)

Tags: windows-10, boot

I recently moved to windows 10 from windows 7.
Once I restarted my PC, it was stuck to **Operating System Not Found**.

Then I used bootable USB to repair a laptop.
On the first go, I tried below steps.

1. Enabled External Boot Device in boot setting menu
2. Completed language setting
3. Clicked on **Repair your computer** which is just below *Install Now* option
4. Opted for **Troubleshoot** option
5. Went to **Advanced options**
6. Clicked on **Startup Repair**

After all the above steps, it just stuck to a blue page mentioning `Error Code: 0xc0000098`

Now every time I try to repair a laptop using a bootable USB, it always stuck to this blue page. I have posted a video having this problem [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnlBphqkOvE).

Answer (score 1):

Find this article [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/error-code-0xc0000098-missing-file-bcd/a5e0d28d-1e25-4ebd-836a-eb8656f41579?auth=1)

Please try these:

Please follow 1 to 5 step (as you've stated on your question) then

6. Click **Command Prompt** and then type the followings and press enter after every command:

   BOOTREC /SCANOS

   BOOTREC /FIXMBR

   BOOTREC /FIXBOOT

   BOOTREC /REBUILDBCD
7. Please restart your computer.

It should work now.

Comment: But whenever I use bootable USB, it directly land to error page. I don't get the setting option.

Comment: Please goto BIOS settings, and change "2nd Boot Priority" to "External Device" and try to boot from it.

Comment: It's not working. I had tried with `2nd Boot Priority`as well as `first Boot Priority` to `External Device`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recreate your bootabel USB you have corrupted it buy using the auto repair option. It should of give you options like press F8 or Esc

Answer (score -1):

Actually the issue was in hard-disk. It was bricked (most probably logically) due to which during booting, laptop was stopped detecting it....

Comment: You should click the checkmark on this answer so the system knows your question is resolved.